# How to add a button floating above the UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Let say I have a UIScrollView and a button, how can I set the button floating above the UIScrollView or Window? (or stick the button in the center of the screen no matter how it will scroll).

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are working with a storyboard, simply add the button above the scroll view and not inside it.
You might also want to set your constraints of the button to the superview of the scrollview and the button to make it completely independent of the scroll view.

so it will be something like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

At the ViewDidLoad Method:

// Adding ScrollView

```
UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]; 
scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);//You Can Edit this with your requirement
```

// Adding Button

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: according to this answer, the button won't float above the `scrollView` as you added it as a subview of the `scrollview`. You should add it as a subview to the main view instead. `[self.view addSubview:button];`